# Where to get the Authorization key to use FCM?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send FCM messages from my app. Currently I have a hard coded key, the "Legacy server key" within my app that I got from the Console.

Something that I should not embed in the application because of security risks.

Where do I get a key/token to safely use within my IOS application?

I have this that gives me a fcmToken:

```
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using it within your client application. It should just be used in your Server. With that said, there is currently no way to get the Server Key (or Authorization Key) from your client app side.

Comment: Hi Al. If I move the sending of FCM messages to a function it also has protection with Authorization keys, where do you get that key?

Comment: Hi Wayne. It's the key found in your Firebase Console > Cloud Messaging tab > Server Key (*not* the Legacy)

Comment: AL, I think you misunderstood me. I'll try to explain a bit more. I unsderstand that the key used for send FCM messages are meant to be used server side and not mobile / client side. So now I have created a server side function Node.js and it also requires an Authentication key, and I do not know where to retrieve it. I presume this will be issued once the user of the mobile is authenticated. I tried "[[[FIRAuth auth] currentUser] getIDTokenWithCompletion" but his token did not work for me. Still got a Unauthorized response.

Comment: Ok got it working.. [[[FIRAuth auth] currentUser] getIDTokenWithCompletion 
is the correct function to get the key.